# remove blank lines from csv using shell script for oracle

Tags: oracle, shell, csv

Hi am using following shell script to create csv from oracle database

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
sqlplus -s user1/user1<<!
Spool on
set heading off
SET FEEDBACK OFF
set wrap off
set colsep ,
SET LINESIZE 200
set trims on
Spool /home/ist/username.csv
select 'username','userid' from dual;
select username,userid from users;
Spool off
EXIT
!
```

I am getting following output

[image]

as you can see there is blank line at first and third row
but am expecting file without blank lines.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the

```
SET PAGESIZE 0
```

command to avoid the blank lines. this also suppresses column headings, so you can remove

```
SET HEADING OFF
```

The command

```
SPOOL on
```

does not make sense because it starts spooling in a file named `on.lst`. So remove this command, too.

If you want to display the heading with the column name 
you can try the following settings

```
set HEADING ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
set WRAP OFF
set COLSEP ,
SET LINESIZE 32767
set NEWPAGE none
set UNDERLINE OFF
set TRIMSPOOL ON
set TRIMOUT ON
set PAGESIZE 50000
```

´heading on´ is the default so you must not set it. It enables the display of the column names when a select starts. `underline off` suppresses the '---' line between column names and data of a select. `pages 50000` sets the pagesize to its maximum value (Oracle 11.2). `linesize 32767` sets the linesize to its maximum value (Oracle 11.2). `newpage none` is necessary to suppress this empty line at the beginning of a page that was the primary concern of your posting.
All this can be found in the [SQL*Plus Command Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve.htm#SQPUG022)

The `termout off` parameter suppresses only output created by a scripts that is executed with the @ or @@ command. It dos not suppress out by a command entered in the SQL*plus console. If you use

```
sqlplus user/passw@connect <<!
...
!
```

you use the here-document syntax of the shell language which simulates the interactive input. So put your sql commands in a script, e.g. `script.sql`, and execute

```
sqlplus user/passw@connect @script.sql
```

then `termout off` will suppress terminal output.

---

Instead of

```
colsep ,
select username,userid
...
```

which returns something like

```
user1                 ,          14
nextuser              ,         236
myuser                ,          11
...
```

you can use leave the COLSEP unchanged and execute

```
select username||','||userid
...
```

to get the following output

```
user1,14
nextuser,236
myuser,11
...
```

Maybe this is useful
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64620/2047

Comment: its working just awesome. just one more thing as you can observe I have used a separate query to create header is there any way to eliminate that and get the header from the same select query which giving the result.

Comment: and one more thing even after using SET TERMOUT OFF  am getting output on terminal

Comment: @AmolSolanke edited this post and added answers to your questions

Answer (score 0):

```
set trimspool on
```

this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

put this on your script

```
sed -i '/^\s*$/d'/home/ist/username.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove lines in `/home/ist/username.csv` without a `,` using

```
grep "," /home/ist/username.csv > /home/ist/username2.csv
# or
sed -i '/^[^,]*$/ d' /home/ist/username.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLPLUS 12.2 has an feature to output CSV, but you need to configure some settings to remove blank lines on it. Here is my approach

```
SET HEADING OFF;
SET PAGES 0;
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
set echo off;
set autotrace off;
set feedback off;
SET TRIM ON;
SET MARKUP CSV ON DELIMITER | QUOTE OFF;
```